# What is the right place to acknowledge another (simultaneous) paper with the same result?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I'm refereeing a paper for a math journal at the moment.  As happens fairly often, some other folks came up with basically the same result independently at the same time, I think the manuscripts showed up on Arxiv a few days apart.

The authors acknowledge this (and of course this is perfectly normal and won't affect my recommendation on whether or not to accept the paper), but they do it at the very end of a long-ish paper as part of the acknowledgements.  This is not unusual but it strikes me as ungracious and an unnecessary hangover from the pre-digital-publishing era when these coincidences were usually addressed by notes added in proof.  Should I ask them to move it up to, say, the end of the introduction, where it is more likely that readers who might be interested in the other paper will actually see it?

Comment: My primary concern with the placement in the acknowledgments is that that section is typically used to acknowledge other parties or works that had a positive influence on the work at hand. If the other paper was simultaneously developed without the knowledge of the authors of the paper at hand, obviously there cannot be any such influence. By mentioning the other paper in the *Acknowledgments* section, the authors confuse the distinction between what was simply there and what was actually used in their work.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Please don't post answers as comments. Your  comment is a good answer and should be posted as one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Τhe sections of *Introduction* and *Related Work* of a paper serve the purpose to inform the reader exactly about related results/attempts/techniques etc in order to put their result in the correct perspective. As such, the "other" result should be mentioned and cited there, preferably with a direct comparison of the possibly different techniques involved. Anything else, could be potentially misleading and/or suspicious and should be avoided.

Comment: Mathematics papers typically don't have an explicit "related work" section. However, I absolutely agree that this needs to be placed in the introduction and possibly in its own section of the introduction, which could suitably be titled "related work".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree that they do not necessarily have "Related Work" section. But, even if not, in this situation they should have a clearly marked paragraph of something like that to clearly indicate and compare the existing related work (and not just acknowledge it)

Comment: Why not in the Discussion section?

Comment: @abukaj Because Discussion section is most often (in fact always) put at the end of the document. Usually these results are discussed in the related work section. If such doesn't exists, there should be a clearly marked paragraph mentioning the related result.

Comment: @abukaj also because math papers have a discussions section even less often than they have a related work section.

Comment: I disagree, because I think this confuses the history of the results. This advice is especially dangerous if one paper's referee requires this, and the other's does not. It then looks like the paper with the rigorous referee is acknowledging the other paper as an influence on them - which is not true!

Comment: @AJK How it can confuse the history of the result? How mentioning related work (and not just acknowledging after 20 pages) can qualify as _dangerous_?

Comment: @AJK Acknowledging the existence of the other paper after 20 papers can actually qualify as suspicious and, as such, dangerous.

Comment: @PsySp - Because when you discuss other work extensively, especially in the introduction, it will look like you are building on previous work - because you have rewritten your paper in response to this other work. If this isn't done carefully, I think it can give the impression that one group is giving up any claim to priority.

Comment: @PsySp - the "note added in proof" approach is not as clear as it should be, but I think it's a well-understood convention that says, "We did this work independently, and want it to be judged separately."

Comment: @AJK If the results are clearly independent works, there can never be any danger in that. What you suggest is to _hide_ the other result because of some fear of misunderstanding, but what you suggest is even more dangerous.

Comment: @AJK I strongly disagree with that. Any related result should be clearly mentioned especially if it's a timely one to _avoid_ misunderstandings. What you propose does not solve, in my opinion, the real issue here.

Comment: @PsySp Like I said, I don't think the standard convention hides information, and I'm not advocating for not mentioning other results. I'm advocating for not editing the Introduction. My basis for worrying about this is experience where one group adds a "Note added" caveat, and the other doesn't. This is bad enough, but if one group changes their introduction, and the other doesn't?

Comment: @AJK this is problem of the group that _doesn't_ change the introduction.

Comment: @AJK btw, I do not think there is "standard convention". In my personal experience, this happened twice and the other person cited and discussed my work in the beginning to make things clear enough that is a completely different approach. I was very glad (and did the same)

Comment: @PsySp - I agree that sensible discussion of other work is better, when it can be done in collaboration with the other team, and approaches are truly different. (I've also seen two papers merged into one when they were near-identical!). But for a *referee* to suggest this, as OP asks, seems like it is more likely to lead to asymmetric handling.

Comment: @AJK A referee makes a suggestion to improve the readability of the paper. If the OP believes that a potential reader would benefit more with the early mention and direct comparison of this related work (which I strongly advice) then the OP has every right to make this suggestion. The authors can respond if they don't like it for one reason or the other. But for the benefit of the future reader, it is highly advisable everything to be put into a clear perspective in the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

I have been in this situation as an co-author. Before the acknowledgements, at the very end of the conclusions we wrote:

> Note added.—Recently, we have become aware of Ref. 22, where a similar
>   approach to ... has been undertaken for ... —and analogous conclusions
>   have been reached regarding ...

They also wrote something similar at the end of their paper. The story was that we submitted to the arxiv within the same week. The papers were almost identical (I think they redid the calculations with our parameters to check if they get the same). In the end, their paper got accepted quite quickly, while in our case, the editor dragged us for one year and half.

Comment: This has been the convention that I have seen, and I think it is accepted as normal in math and physics. I agree with OP, though, that it isn't very prominent!

Answer (score 3):

I have seen papers that were in a slightly different situation than yours: on the cusp of going to print when a similar paper made its first appearance (on arXiv or in a journal if it didn't get put on arXiv first).  These papers often include a small paragraph at the end of the paper, immediately before the acknowledgments section, citing the paper, summarizing the results, and include a statement such as "this paper was published as we were going to print".

Comment: Agreed but this isn't the situation here so I don't see how you're answering the question.